# How can I set "isfocusable" property to false for UIElements ( buttons) in WPF?

Tags: wpf, focus, uielement

I'm trying to set the property of `UIElement` to not focusable, but there does not seem to be a isfocusable property for buttons. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [Focusable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks, yap, exactly what Im looking for :D

Answer (score 2):

What about `<Button Focusable="False" />`